# Winform Is scrolling up itself when click bottom of form

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, click, mouse

My application is windows based and I have windows form with 4 group boxes with many combo boxes into It with data binding.

Issue:

When I scroll my page down and try to type or click to bottom part of page, Form itself is scrolling up instead of staying focus there. Do I need to set any property or write any code? I've been searching for this annoying Issue but no success so far. Any help is highly appreciated.

I am using vb.net/VS 2010/Windows form/SQL 2008r2

Apologies If my question Is not clear. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I am afraid this is not very clear. At least for me. Could you try to add a screenshot for example?

Comment: "Apologies If my question Is not clear." - You are correct, it is not clear.  Of course, you can get around this by editing your post with code!

Comment: Winforms does its best to keep the control with the focus visible.  An important usability feature.  Make sure that whatever you are clicking on can receive the focus.

Comment: As it stands now it is hard to give an answer, if you include the minimal code to reproduce this as in [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) you will be more likely to get a answer.